How to use django orm in python-socketio inside django project?
Now I created new app "ws" (it's in INSTALLED_APPS) and I use this code there in views.py:
import socketio

#from task_tracker.models import TaskColumn

sio = socketio.Server(cors_allowed_origins="*")
app = socketio.WSGIApp(sio)


@sio.event
def connect(sid, environ):
    print(sid, 'connected')

@sio.event
def disconnect(sid):
    print(sid, 'disconnected')

@sio.event
def getColumns(sid, environ):
    print(environ)



I run this code with:
gunicorn -b 127.0.0.1:5000 --threads 50 views:app

And everything is fine till I try to import my model from the other app. The error is:
(venv) dbte5@Denis-MBP ws % gunicorn -b 127.0.0.1:5000 --threads 50 views:app

[2024-04-05 18:00:52 +0500] [3112] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
[2024-04-05 18:00:52 +0500] [3112] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:5000 (3112)
[2024-04-05 18:00:52 +0500] [3112] [INFO] Using worker: gthread
[2024-04-05 18:00:52 +0500] [3113] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 3113
[2024-04-05 18:00:52 +0500] [3113] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 609, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/gthread.py", line 95, in init_process
    super().init_process()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 371, in import_app
    mod = importlib.import_module(module)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/dbte5/desktop/programming/job/CosmoProjects-CRM/src/ws/views.py", line 3, in <module>
    from task_tracker.models import TaskColumn
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'task_tracker'

How can I handle it and use django orm to fetch data?
Btw I've tried to start django with:
gunicorn -b :8000 --threads 100 --access-logfile - django_socketio.wsgi:application

as it mentioned in github django_socketio, but it didn't help

If you're using a virtual environment for your Django project, make sure it's activated before running Gunicorn. This ensures that Gunicorn has access to all the installed packages, including your Django app.
